# Windows workflow 4.5 - Send notifications at regular intervals

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am having an approval workflow. The client is asp.net mvc 4 and the client calls out to a WEB API. This WEB API in turn hosts the WF using WorkflowAplication class. The scenario here is, if a request is not approved for a certain time, i need the persisted workflow to load send an email and persist again. Is this scenario possible somehow using WF 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a timer object outside of the workflows but trigger it from within the workflow (Pass it into the workflow as an Argument).  Then when the timer fires you can use the event to restart the workflow from a persist point, send the e-mail and then persist again.